# How can I encode the parameters of a javascript function properly?

Tags: javascript, html

I inspect the element in my browser and I see this , everything seems to work properly

```
<button id="cb0" name="cb0" class="btn btn-success btn-large" onclick="getMetier(11-1011.00)">Président Directeur Général</button>
```

But when I do click on that button, it calls the function, but when I do a `console.log` of the parameters in the called function here what I have :

```
« -1000 »
```

What I have tried so far :

- Use `escape()` on the parameter (Not work)
- Use `encodeURI()` on the parameter (Not work)

What I have done bad ?

Comment: Work fine, it's solved, I feel kinda stupid:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect to get when you subtract one thousand and eleven from eleven?

Are you trying to pass the value as a string instead of a number? If so, just put it in quotes.

```
 onclick="getMetier('11-1011.00')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes

```
onclick="getMetier('11-1011.00')"
```